# Generate additional row after last entry for each company

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the columns `date`, `company`, `value`.

The dates are always the day of the end of the quarter, so 2020-12-31, 2021-03-31, etc.

I need a query that shows a boolean value called "write_off" on the *subsequent* quarter after the latest entry for each company.

For example, if the data is:

```
2020-12-31 CompanyA 100
2021-03-31 CompanyA 120
2021-06-30 CompanyA 120
```

Then the query should show:

```
2020-12-31 CompanyA 100  false
2021-03-31 CompanyA 120  false
2021-06-30 CompanyA 120  false
2021-09-30 CompanyA null true
```

I've tried to use `LEAD()` to create a "next quarter" row, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Actual table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and your version of Postgres would be helpful.

Comment: I took the liberty to rephrase the title and sharpen the explanation. Correct me if I got that wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT date, company, value, false AS write_off FROM tbl
 
UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT DISTINCT ON (company)
      (date + interval '3 month')::date, company
     , null AS value, true AS write_off
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY company, date DESC NULLS LAST
);
```

We need the extra parentheses, else `ORDER BY` would apply to the whole `UNION ALL` query (the combined set).

Depending on undisclosed cardinalities, there may be faster (optimized) query variants to get the latest row per company, especially if there are many companies and many rows per company. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)